# TortoiseGit show log for remote branch

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, tortoisegit

I am new to Git and bitbucket so excuse me if this is a very simple question.

I am using bitbucket in conjunction with TortoiseGit and I've set it up according to:

http://guganeshan.com/blog/setting-up-git-and-tortoisegit-with-bitbucket-step-by-step.html

and it is all working correctly.

What I would  like to do is that when I click on show log from tortoiseGit I see the log of the remote branch ( hosted on bitbucket ) not that of the local branch

I managed to see the remote's branch log by doing:

```
git fetch
git log remote/test
```

from gitbash ( https://github.com/abhikp/git-test/wiki/View-the-commit-log-of-a-remote-branch )

Is there any way I can accomplish the same task from within tortoiseGit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can emulate those steps in [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/):

- `git fetch origin`:

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TortoiseGit/TortoiseGit/master/doc/images/en/Fetch.png]

- `git log origin/test`:

In the log dialog box, select "All branches", to see the `remotes/origin/test`

[image: http://dev.opencascade.org/doc/overview/html/OCCT_GitGuide_V2_image026.png]

you can see [other illustrations in the dev guide](http://dev.opencascade.org/doc/overview/html/occt_dev_guides__git_guide.html).

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer shows all commits on all branches which isn't quite what was asked, and often shows too much information to understand. You can do the following to view just a single remote branch instead.

- Perform "git fetch" as usual either from the TortoiseGit or from the command line.
- In the "Log Messages" dialog, click on the blue branch name in the top left corner to open the "Browse references" dialog
  [image: Click on the blue branch name]
- In the "Browse references" dialog select the remote branch you want to view, it will most likely be under refs->remotes->origin. Then click on the "OK" button to return to your "Log Messages" dialog. The commit history should now show the details of the remote branch that you selected.

[image: Select the remote branch of interest to you]

Comment: Interesting (+1) and more accurate than my answer.

Comment: But what if you want to view a tag alongside another branch? I can't seem to figure out how to go under origin for one branch and then tags for another ref...as soon as I switch nodes, it looses my selection.  I can use 'all branches' to see everything, but it's a mess.

Comment: @ChrisKnoll, Looks like you're asking a different question. You should create a new question since it will be seen by more people instead of asking it in a comment.

Comment: Awesome. Now how do I get TortoiseGit to do that by default every time I open the log, and for bonus points perform an automatic Fetch first? It strikes me as crazy that even using TortoiseGit it's 10 mouse clicks to Fetch, open the Log and switch to the remote branch just to get a useful view of my current repo branch.

Comment: @Neutrino, Looks like you're asking a different question as well so you could try creating your own stack overflow question or alternatively suggest it as a feature request to the maintainers of TortoiseGit